# <Button> won't work with popup. (HTML, CSS, JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't quite figure this out. I've created a smiley with css color values. But when I added the button it made the face ugly. (It added a circle around the center of the smiley design) I've tried forwarding the button tag with the same element of the popup which is `popScroll`. But still my luck has yet to shine through.

When I click the submit button in the bottom right, the popup will open and refresh, which is fine. It shows it works, but I really want to get this smiley face I've made to work with this popup so I can move further with design.

Can someone please show me what i'm doing wrong? I'm really new to this, and would love some insight on how to be a better coder and developer.
When you click the button now(the smiley face) it will do a alert which says hi, I was just testing to see a transparent button over the face would work.

I'll be active to respond to any questions and responses immediately.

My code can be found [here](http://codepen.io/SaintMichael/pen/vEMLBa).

```
<div class="popScroll">
    <div class="popup"> 
    <!-- Smiley button -->
    <button onclick="alert('hi');" class="smiley">
        <!--<div class = "smiley"></i></div>-->
    </button>
```

Comment: .popup button{
  border:none;
}

Comment: A lot of that code is not necessary and is noise to the question, note that the question should be an minimal example.

Comment: Thank-you Spencer, this is my first question. I'll be sure to be much more precise with future questions, thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a border has been added higher up in the css.

Remove this and you should be sorted.

```
.smiley {
    border: none;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEwEJj)

Comment: Good eye and thank-you! I would've never seen that. I'll be sure to be much more careful.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
.smiley:focus{ outline: none}
```

Comment: I was very vague in my question, and that was a poor decision on my end. The problem i'm having is the button itself doesn't open the popup. I apologize for that.